# Terms used to describe the Pauli exclusion principle

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electrons

This is a very simple question. Today, someone explained to me that the Pauli exclusion principle says that "no two electrons can occupy the same energy state". However, I believe that this language is not precise as two electrons can occupy the same energy state, allowing they have different spin. Rather it is the quantum state that cannot be the same.

So, my question is, is it wrong to say energy state?

Comment: I’d go one step further and argue that the term ‘energy state’ is not well-defined. If they meant that two electrons can’t have the same energy, then they should just say that (even though it’s obviously wrong).

Comment: The principle means that electrons cannot have the same set of quantum numbers and be in the same state. You realise this by saying that they must have different spin. (Electrons have two spin quantum numbers. Spin quantum number in your question means magnetic/projection/azimuthal spin $m_s=\pm1/2$, whereas the other electron spin quantum number is always the same and is $S=1/2$)

Comment: Depending on the level at which it is taught, you will find different statements, some of which are just wrong. Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/111062/72973